# SQLMap not showing output in command prompt

Tags: python-2.7, sqlmap

I am having a strange issue with SQLMap.

It seems to be outputting text but it is not visible. I know it is outputting text because I can actually copy it and paste it somewhere else to see it.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

The large black area is where the text should be visible but isn't.

I am doing this on windows but on Linux it works fine. Any idea of what is going on or how I can troubleshoot this?

Edit 1: I seemed to have an outdated version. However updating to the latest release of SQLMap did not change anything.